# Need to show $|f(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2) | \le 4$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ be differentiable everywhere with $f(-\sqrt 2,-\sqrt 2)=0$ and let $$|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)| \le |\sin (x^2+y^2)|, |\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)| \le |\cos(x^2+y^2)|$$ for all $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$. Prove that $$|f(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)|\le 4.$$

I tried to apply this:
[image]

with $p=(-\sqrt 2,-\sqrt 2), x=(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)$. I got $$|f(x)|\le 2\sqrt 2(|\sin 4| + |\cos 4|)\le 4\sqrt 2.$$ But I need a better estimate. How should I proceed?

Comment: Are you given the value of $f$ at some point?

Comment: @Strants Yes, I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that $|\sin \theta| +|\cos \theta | \leq \sqrt 2$ where $\theta = x^{2}+y^{2}$.

Comment: How do I prove this?

Comment: Render $(|\sin\theta|+|\cos\theta|)^2 = \sin^2 \theta + 2|\sin\theta||\cos\theta| + \cos^2 \theta = 1 + |\sin 2\theta|$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Oh, because of the way the answer is stated I thought the fact that $\theta=x^2+y^2$ plays a role, but it's not...